# Does grpc port can be connected by more than one client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc

Does grpc port can be connected by more than one client?
In fabric, peer's port is 7051, can i get two cli clients to connect the port at the same time?
I use the netstat cmd find the status of the port is ESTABLISHED, so can i use another client to connect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default port for invoking chaincode on the peer is 7051.  Multiple clients can concurrently invoke chaincode.  The only limit will be based on the number of open file descriptors set on the host system running the peer.

On Unix based systems, you can check this by running:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` to see the total enforced across all processes

`ulimit -n` to see the per process limit for the current user

That should give enough to Google more about file descriptor limits.

Comment: the number of open file descriptors----how can i find this setting?

Comment: Updated answer above with a few more details

Comment: I checked that, get 1635720 and 65535, so that is enough already.